# Fabric Js arc overlapping while creating arc

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to create cloud shape like rectangle with equal arcs in fabric.js. I am using the circle function for creating this. Below is my code

```
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o)
    {
    if (!isDown) return;

    var wd=pointer.x-origX;
    var wd=parseInt(wd/10);
    var ht=pointer.y-origY;
    var ht=parseInt(ht/10);
    var strcircle="";
    group = new fabric.Group();
    for($i=0;$i<wd;$i++)
    {
        circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        left: origX,
        top: origY,
        //angle: 0,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        width: pointer.x-origX,
        height: pointer.y-origY,
        startAngle: Math.PI,
        endAngle: 0,
        clockwise: true,
        stroke: '#000',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fill: '',
        originX: $i, originY: 5

    });
    group.addWithUpdate(circle1);

    }"

canvas.add(group);
}
```

Straight line arcs are creating properly but arcs are overlapping on each other. When canvas.clear() is used it works properly that is it outputs single straight line with arcs.

[This image show how arc are overlapping on each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itV34.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is arc not showing proper when you add arc in to group?

Comment: Yes arc are building properly but it is overlapping on top of each other as we drag with mouse.

Comment: I think you need to reassign coordinates of each object while drag mouse.